# Using the mkdir terminal command

Tags: mkdir

I've installed the dependencies, downloaded the source files, then installed the 'Reicast' Dreamcast console emulator. I now need to create the directory for the bios and flash files: `mkdir .local/share/reicast/data/`. This fails to work. I get this error message: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.local/share/reicast/data’: No such file or directory`. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/reicast/  
mkdir ~/.local/share/reicast/data/
```

Comment: Ha you spotted the same mistake? >:-D

Comment: Karel's answer was perfect. I had to create the recast folder first followed by the data folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it not working?

Your command is only correct if you are in your /home/$USER/.

```
mkdir .local/share/reicast/data/
```

should be

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/reicast/data/
```

In case "reicast" does not exist yet you also need the `-p` option with `mkdir`.